# hasNext and findInLine in Scanner Class using array

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, I have years experience in C, hope you can help me.

I have a decimal file and I need to find a header and from there pick the data and again look for the header.
Lets say my file looks like this:

```
480 124 125 001 047 001 047 001 480 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 047 001 480 002 002 002 002 002 002 002 002
```

my header is:

```
001 047 001 480
```

the header is stored at an int array called "header".

I tried multiple ways-
the code:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(this.header[0]);
Integer i2 = new Integer(this.header[1]);
Integer i3 = new Integer(this.header[2]);
Integer i4 = new Integer(this.header[3]);

nextDec.hasNext(i1.toString() + i2.toString() + i3.toString() + i4.toString());
```

returns false, though I expect true.
it returns false even if I delete the leading zeroes of the header numbers in the file (in reality I can't delete them)

the code:

```
nextDec.findInLine(i1.toString() + " " + i2.toString() + " " + i3.toString() + " "
                + i4.toString());
```

returns null, though I expect it to return the header.
it returns the header if I delete the leading zeroes of the header numbers in the file why didn't it work with the hasNext method?

The code:

```
nextDec.findInLine(Arrays.toString(header));
```

has no output whatsoever, why is that?
how can I detect the header, with leading zeroes, retrieve the data and re-find it? is it possible to find the location (index) of where the header was found?

thank you

I'll try to be clearer. I have streaming data recorded on the PC using monitor software. the data is logged to a file in decimal form with leading zeroes (to have 3 digit numbers) and spaces between the numbers. the file contains multiple buffers.
the data buffer starts with a 4 byte header, I need to find in the file the header and collect the data that follows it to the appropriate variables to be displayed in a graph. I was thinking of using the nextInt, nextFloat for that according to the type of data I want to read after the header is found.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain with an example of what you expect as output. 1) Find location of header in line. 2)??

Comment: You're looking for a specific string, without spaces or leading zeros. That string doesn't appear in your input. Why do you expect `hasNext()` to find it?

Comment: I'll try to be clearer. I have streaming data recorded on the PC using monitor software. the data is logged to a file in decimal form with leading zeroes (to have 3 digit numbers) and spaces between the numbers. the file contains multiple buffers.
the data buffer starts with a 4 byte header, I need to find in the file the header and collect the data that follows it to the appropriate variables to be displayed in a graph. I was thinking of using the nextInt, nextFloat for that according to the type of data I want to read after the header is found.

Comment: How you header array is defined? If you use, for example, 047 literal in java, it treats it as oct and when converting to string results in 39 (dec), so you get not what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to use header as delimiter and then scan input.
But I think it would be better do do it manually intead of using scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "480 124 125 001 047 001 047 001 480 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 047 001 480 002 002 002 002 002 002 002 002\n";

        int header[] = new int[] {1, 47, 1, 480};
        String stringHeader = "";
        for (int e : header) {
            stringHeader += String.format("%03d ", e);
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
        scanner.useDelimiter(stringHeader);

        // Skipping everything before first header
        scanner.skip(".*?"+stringHeader);

        // Now we get data between headers
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(   scanner.next()   );
        }

    }
}
```

Output (two tokens after first and second header):

```
001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 001 
002 002 002 002 002 002 002 002
```

Is it something you want to get?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I must use some kind of read file method, I can't copy the strings to the application (the txt files can be a few MB long).
Also, since I don't know if there is an error in buffer length the skip method might cause out of sync error (it happens that there is an error in transmission and a short buffer arrives accidentally).
I know there isn't union in java as in C, can I refer to part of the stream as byte/short/int/float using scanner? is there a better method?
thank you again

Comment: if I have an error in reception of a buffer I might get a shorter buffer than expected. But now I get it, I will be able to find the length using array length (every scanner.next(); will give me a exasperated buffer).
how do I do it using read file rather than copying the data to a string in the application?
thanks

Comment: You can get size of a file using File class: `new File("/path/to/file.txt").length()`